# Why the default action for a form is caHide?

Tags: delphi

Why when the user clicks the close button of a form, the default action is caHide instead of caFree?
From programming point of view seems so counter intuitive.
There is a hidden reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Actually it is not always caHide. For a MDI child form it is either caMinimize or caNone.

Comment: Because, by default, forms you add to the project are auto-created.

Comment: You would have to ask Borland why they chose `caHide` as the default. But I *suspect* it is because the most common way to use Forms at the time was to auto-create ALL of the Forms in a project, so `caHide` would make it easy to create the Forms once and reuse them over and over by simply hiding and showing them. Of course, we know better nowadays, and this is not suggested practice anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sertac said, it's because the Delphi IDE expects forms to be created at the beginning of your application and kept there while the application is alive. That is, when you create a new form, a global variable for that form is created in the form's unit. This variable is initialized with a new form in the Project's main block using `Application.CreateForm(...)`. There are no explicit calls to a free, these forms are destroyed at the end of the application during TApplication.Destroy. With the default action of caHide, this works just fine - you get a valid instance of a form at the beginning and this instance will remain valid until the end of the application. If the default action were `caFree`, the contents of the global variable would get invalidated the first time a form is closed (because there's no way of knowing which place should be set to `nil`) and you would get a pointer which looks valid but would cause various problems (EAccessViolation if you were lucky, "random" memory overwriting if not) on use.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thanks.